# Adding zero valued entries so that all groups have entries for the same items

Tags: r, dplyr, rcharts, data-manipulation

I'm trying to use [Rcharts](http://rcharts.io/) to create a stacked bar chart across a number of recorded regions (stacking separate group values on top of each other). The data is in a format similar to below.

```
Region | Group | Value
----------------------
USA    |   A   |   5
USA    |   B   |   3
USA    |   C   |   1
UK     |   A   |   4
UK     |   B   |   6
France |   C   |   3
```

Using the below code produces a grouped bar chart which works fine. However the stacked button does nothing to change the plot.

```
nPlot(Value ~ Region, group = 'Group', 
      data = example_data, 
      type = 'multiBarChart')
```

Looking at [this](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/545) thread it seems the problem might be that some Regions don't have entries for all present groups (e.g. the UK lacks an entry for C, and France lacks entries for A and B).

What I'm not sure of is how to add entries with Value == 0 so that all Regions have an entry for every present Group. So that the above data is transformed to this (the ordering of entries doesn't matter).

```
Region | Group | Value
----------------------
USA    |   A   |   5
USA    |   B   |   3
USA    |   C   |   1
UK     |   A   |   4
UK     |   B   |   6
UK     |   C   |   0
France |   A   |   0
France |   B   |   0
France |   C   |   3
```

This will ultimately be placed within the reactive component of a Shiny app so efficient solutions in particular would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `complete()` from the `tidyr` package:

> This is a wrapper around expand(), left_join() and replace_na that's
>   useful for completing missing combinations of data. It turns
>   implicitly missing values into explicitly missing values.

```
library(tidyr)
library(rCharts)

df %>% 
  complete(Region, Group, fill = list(Value = 0)) %>%
  nPlot(Value ~ Region, group = 'Group', 
        data = ., 
        type = 'multiBarChart')
```

---

**Grouped**

[image]

**Stacked**

[image]

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Region = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("France", 
"UK", "USA"), class = "factor"), Group = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    Value = c(5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 3L)), .Names = c("Region", 
"Group", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```